# How do I change the position of a Label inside of a Frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, frame

I am trying to place my Labels so that they are aligned to the left of the Frames. However, they are showing up in the center as shown below. What do I have to place in config to align them correctly?
[image]

Here is the part of my code that deals with this:

```
this.topFrame = Frame(this.chatWindow,relief="sunken",bd=1)
this.midFrame = Frame(this.chatWindow,relief="sunken",bd=1)
this.topFrame.pack(fill="x",expand = True)
this.midFrame.pack(fill="x",expand = True)
```

## Adds Posters to Top Users Frame

```
for poster in topPosters:
   label = Label(this.topFrame,text=poster)
   label.config(anchor=W,justify=LEFT)
   label.pack()
```

## Adds Messages to Message Frame

```
for message in messageList:
   label = Label(this.midFrame,text=message)
   label.config(anchor=W,justify=LEFT)
   label.pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `anchor` attribute of the label to `"w"` (west):

```
label = Label(this.midFrame, text=message, anchor="w")
```

The other problem is that you need to use the `fill` attribute of `pack` so that the labels fill the whole row.

```
label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I knew I placed something wrong in there.

Comment: Hm, weird. I tried this but they are still in the center.

Comment: @Shan: I'm sorry. I forgot to notice you are also not using the `fill` attribute when packing. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `grid` instead of `pack`:

```
label.grid(sticky = W)
```